# How to fillna() all columns of a dataframe from a single row of another dataframe with identical structure

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I have a `train_df` and a `test_df`, which come from the same original dataframe, but were split up in some proportion to form the training and test datasets, respectively.

Both train and test dataframes have identical structure:

- A PeriodIndex with daily buckets
- n number of columns that represent observed values in those time buckets e.g. Sales, Price, etc.

I now want to construct a `yhat_df`, which stores predicted values for each of the columns. In the "naive" case, `yhat_df` columns values are simply the last observed training dataset value.

So I go about constructing `yhat_df` as below:

```
import pandas as pd
yhat_df = pd.DataFrame().reindex_like(test_df)
yhat_df[train_df.columns[0]].fillna(train_df.tail(1).values[0][0], inplace=True)
yhat_df(train_df.columns[1]].fillna(train_df.tail(1).values[0][1], inplace=True)
```

This appears to work, and since I have only two columns, the extra typing is bearable.

I was wondering if there is simpler way, especially one that does not need me to go column by column.

I tried the following but that just populates the column values correctly where the PeriodIndex values match. It seems `fillna()` attempts to do a `join()` of sorts internally on the Index:

```
yhat_df.fillna(train_df.tail(1), inplace=True)
```

If I could figure out a way for `fillna()` to ignore index, maybe this would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with a dictionary to fill each column with a different value, so I think:

```
yhat_df = yhat_df.fillna(train_df.tail(1).to_dict('records')[0])
```

should work, but if I understand well what you do, then even directly create the dataframe with:

```
yhat_df = pd.DataFrame(train_df.tail(1).to_dict('records')[0], 
                       index = test_df.index, columns = test_df.columns)
```

Comment: Amazing! The only side-effect I see is that the resulting yhat_df has the order of columns sorted alphabetically. I am still on Pandas 0.19.2, so don't have the option to use `to_dict(orient='records', into=OrderedDict)`. This should not be a big problem since my code doesn't do anything with column positions.

Comment: @Cod.ie if you want the columns in the same order, maybe you can add the parameter `columns` when you create the dataframe, I edited my answer for it.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :)